# Como excluir valores repetidos de apenas uma variável de um data frame no RStudio?

Tags: dataframe, r

Tenho um Data.frame com 3 variáveis. Uma delas é numérica, e possui valores repetidos. Gostaria de eliminar os valores repetidos dessa variável numérica, junto com sua linha. Dos valores repetidos não importa qual linha será mantida.

Já verifiquei que a função unique() encontra linhas (casos) identicas e mantém apenas uma. Mas não é essa a situação. No meu data.frame os casos (linhas) são todos diferentes, porém a variável númerica em questão possui valores iguais. Não quero ter nenhum valor repetido nessa variável numérica.

Answer (score 0):

Se a variável repetir nas 3 colunas, você pode usar a função `distinct` do dplyr para tirar as colunas repetidas:

```
df <- distinct(df)
```

Se quiser remover uma coluna, em específico :

```
df <- distinct(df, column_name, .keep_all= TRUE)
```